# OpenVPN leaks IP for one host only

Tags: openvpn

I've been trying to solve this for the past week and I can't figure this out.

I've pretty much boilerplate OpenVPN server using TUN running and then I've 3 separate HTTP servers each running Nginx with basic auth. My goal is eventually to replace basic auth with IP filtering.

However the problem is that one of the server keeps receiving my own IP instead of VPN's. Other two servers gets VPN's IP and so does every other IP checking site I've tried. All servers have same Nginx configuration and there's nothing special about that one server.

Initially we thought it might be due subnets because all the servers, including VPN, were in the same datacenter. I cloned VPN server to another datacenter to make sure it's not in the same subnet but the problem persists.

Like I said, I've no idea what's going on here so I really hope somebody might have seen this before.

**server.conf**

```
 port 1194
 proto udp

 dev tun

 ca ca.crt
 cert server.crt

 dh dh2048.pem

 server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

 ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

 push "redirect-gateway def1"
 push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"

 keepalive 10 120

 comp-lzo

 user nobody
 group nogroup

 persist-key
 persist-tun

 status openvpn-status.log

 log openvpn.log

 verb 5
```

Comment: Are you actually accessing the servers over the VPN tunnel? Evidence please

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/alfBtMK.png - there's a screenshot. At the top you can see my own IP leaking through VPN, the second is OpenVPN's IP and the bottom is also OpenVPN's IP. These all are obviously loaded while Tunnelblick is tunneling everything through VPN connection.

Comment: in that picture I see what looks like two copies of Windows Notepad, each one containing an IP address.

Comment: Those are three Safari windows each showing IP address that the server sees - what other proof do you need? Frankly I've been debugging this thing so much for the past week that I know 100% that the traffic is going through VPN tunnel so unless you've a specific test you want me to run to prove that it doesn't, please reply only if you've ideas how to debug or solve this problem.

Comment: You've got one (Mac) client, one VPN, and this is the response from the three servers across that one VPN connection? Are the servers reachable without the VPN?

Comment: Does traceroute from the client differ between the three server targets?

Comment: Traceroute gave something interesting. It looks like that all other requests first query 10.8.0.1 but that one particular server goes straight to 192.168.1.1. And the answer to your earlier question is that yes, these are reachable without the VPN.

Comment: Actually @roaima you just helped to solve this in a way. Your traceroute lead me to look at routing tables and in there I found out that because this particular server was originally used to test OpenVPN installation, Tunnelblick hadn't properly deleted routes so because of this everything went straight pass VPN with this one IP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`traceroute` and then `netstat` shows that the client application, Tunnelblick, hasn't deleted older routes. Because of this everything for the awkward server goes direct rather then via the VPN.